# android manifest error @xml/file paths

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="gt.otomat">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="true"/>

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="28" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".otomat">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"
                ></meta-data>
        </provider>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

ı copied this code from github but I have an error.ı am using tesstwo library for ocr.(tesseract ocr) 
ı have an error "android:resource="@xml/file_paths" in this place. I copied everyhing manifest, main activity and activity_main.xml but it gives an error.

thank you for your helps....

Comment: What's the error message? If it's something like "No resource found...", then you likely missed copying the `res/xml/` folder.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

**First add your provider tag inside the applicaton**

```
<application
...
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="zm.mytestapplication.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
</provider>
```

**Create a file_path in your xml folder like this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<external-path
    name="my_images"   
    path="Android/data/org.projects.cameraapp/files/Pictures" />

  </paths>
```

make sure you have the correct paths in the .xml file

Answer (score 3):

You are using provider to define file path. First of all create `xml` folder under **res** directory. Then create **xml** file(in your case **file_paths**). In your xml file define path as follows.

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="my_images" path="images/"/>
</paths>
```

here `path` is your storage path where you want to store your files.
for more info visit the [Google Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider).